# GradientMap usage to train model, all output converge on my first X value

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

Growing past using model.fit() to train my model, I wanted to use a GradientMap to implement the training of a basic model that tried to produce the square of a value.

```
x_data = [1., 2., 3.]
y_data = [1., 4., 9.]
```

The full code below is what is used to train the model. The model updates as the training loop occurs, but all of the output values are the same. Initial untrained model produces something like:

```
[[[0.51774]]]
[[[0.53543544]]]
[[[0.5530421]]]
```

Essentially random values (expected)... as the training loop goes, the predictions all seem to be updating based on the first X value of 1.0, and not training on 2.0 and 3.0.

2500 loops in here is the output of the prediction:

```
2500
[[[0.9999831]]]
[[[0.99999976]]]
[[[1.]]]
```

I was expecting it to predict 1, 4, and 9... or at least converge towards those numbers.

Complete Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import models, layers, losses, metrics


def create_model():
  model = models.Sequential()

  input_layer = layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(None, 1), activation='relu')
  model.add(input_layer)
  model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
  model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))  # todo: understand activation better

  model.compile(loss=losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), metrics=[metrics.Accuracy()], optimizer='adam')

  return model, input_layer


x_data = [1., 2., 3.]
y_data = [1., 4., 9.]

model, input_layer = create_model()

def run_predictions():
  output = model.predict(x_data)
  print(output)

run_predictions()

for i in range(10000):
  if i % 100 == 0:
    print(i)
    run_predictions()

  for x in x_data:
    x = tf.Variable(x, name='input')

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      tape.watch(x)
      y = model(tf.Variable([[x]]))
      loss = x**2 - y

    dy_dx = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    model.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(dy_dx, model.trainable_weights))
```

Thanks for your help in advance!!

Comment: "understand activation better" is a great idea; sigmoid is limited to the range of [0,1] so it is impossible to get any higher outputs.

Comment: I tried several other activation functions for my last layer. All with bad results. Sometimes the values would track together, other ones diverged, but not to anywhere useful. Is there an activation function you would recommend or some reading that might be helpful?

Comment: Why is the loss x^2 - y? This is not a standard loss, it is unlikely to work, I recommend MSE for this problem.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thanks for letting me know that wasn't a standard way of doing things. I changed the loss calculation too `loss = losses.MSE(x**2, y)` and the same type of results are happening where all of the values come out the same.